# Retrieving children of FlipView in UWP

Tags: uwp, flipview

I have a flipView which has a Grid inside. Is there any way to find the grid as child of flipView item?

I have tried using FlipView.FindChild(). But it returns null value. This is the sample xaml code,

```
<FlipView>
    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType = "data:SampleData">
             <Grid x:Name="SampleGrid">
                 ===Sample Code====
             </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your scenario, it is recommended to use [VisualTreeHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper?view=winrt-22621#examples) to find the button in the Grid.

```
<Grid>
    <FlipView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items, Mode=OneWay}">
        <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid PointerEntered="Grid_PointerEntered" PointerExited="Grid_PointerExited">
                    
                    <MediaElement  Source="{Binding mediaSource}" AutoPlay="True" />
                    <Button x:Name="btnTest"  Content="Test"  Background="Yellow" Click="Button_Click" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Collapsed"></Button>
                  
                    <Border Background="#A5000000" Height="80" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="26.667" Foreground="#CCFFFFFF" Padding="15,20" />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    </FlipView>

</Grid>
```

---

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
 {
    
     public ObservableCollection<FlipViewItem> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<FlipViewItem>();

     public MainPage()
     {
         this.InitializeComponent();
         LoadData(); // Load your data here (e.g., from a service or local storage)
     }

     private void LoadData()
     {
         // Example data (replace with your actual data)
         Items.Add(new FlipViewItem { Name = "Test1", mediaSource = "ms-appx:///Assets/test1.mp4" });
         Items.Add(new FlipViewItem { Name = "Test2", mediaSource = "ms-appx:///Assets/test2.mp4" });
         Items.Add(new FlipViewItem { Name = "Test3", mediaSource = "ms-appx:///Assets/test3.mp4" });
         Items.Add(new FlipViewItem { Name = "Test4", mediaSource = "ms-appx:///Assets/test4.mp4" });
         // Add more items as needed
     }
   
     private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {

     }


     private void Grid_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
     {
         Grid grid = (Grid)sender;

         Button btnTest = FindChild<Button>(grid);

         if (btnTest != null)
         {
             // Do something with the found TextBox
             btnTest.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
         }
     }

     private void Grid_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
     {
         Grid grid = (Grid)sender;

         Button btnTest = FindChild<Button>(grid);

         if (btnTest != null)
         {
             // Do something with the found TextBox
             btnTest.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
         }
     }

     public static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent) where T : DependencyObject
     {
         if (parent == null)
             return null;

         int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
         for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
         {
             var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
             if (child is T typedChild)
                 return typedChild;

             // Recursively search deeper into nested containers
             T result = FindChild<T>(child);
             if (result != null)
                 return result;
         }

         return null; // Child not found
     }

     public class FlipViewItem
     {

         public string Name { get; set; }
         public string mediaSource { get; set; }


     }
 }
```

### Update

```
    public static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (parent == null)
            return null;

        int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            if (child is T typedChild)
                return typedChild;

            // Recursively search deeper into nested containers
            T result = FindChild<T>(child);
            if (result != null)
                return result;
        }

        return null; // Child not found
    }


    public static void FindChildList<T>(List<T> results, DependencyObject startNode) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(startNode);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            DependencyObject current = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(startNode, i);
            if (current is T typedChild)
            {
                results.Add(typedChild);
            }
            FindChildList(results, current);
        }
    }
  

    private void FlipView_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FlipView flipView = (FlipView)sender;
        List<Grid> grids= new List<Grid>();
        FindChildList<Grid>(grids,flipView);

        for (int i = 0; i < grids.Count; i++)
        {
            Grid grid = grids[i];
            Button btnTest = FindChild<Button>(grid);

            if (btnTest != null)
            {
                btnTest.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
      
       
    }

    private void FlipView_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FlipView flipView = (FlipView)sender;
        List<Grid> grids = new List<Grid>();
        FindChildList<Grid>(grids, flipView);

        for (int i = 0; i < grids.Count; i++)
        {
            Grid grid = grids[i];
            Button btnTest = FindChild<Button>(grid);

            if (btnTest != null)
            {
               
                btnTest.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Junjie Zhu I have a question regarding your implementation, 
Instead of Grid, can we call the FindChild method in FlipView control. I mean instead of Grid can we use the PointerEntered and PointerExit event from FlipView? I have tried to use it to search Grid type object but it returns Scrollbars and Four Arrow buttons of FlipView control. Not the actual button inside DataTemplate.

Comment: you need to find all Grid in FlipView, please check the update in my answer. BTW, please keep one question in one thread.